# Swift - edit contraints on the last cell from UICollection View

Tags: ios, swift, exception, uicollectionview, generics

I would like edit a contraint to the last cell from UICollectionView.
In my cell I have a image with contraints on center of the cell
I want to align it to left of the cell.

I am trying it:

```
let cell : mycellCollection = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("mycellCollection", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! mycellCollection

var oldrole : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell.imageview1, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: cell, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
var newrole : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell.imageview1,  attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: cell, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 8);

cell.imageview1.removeConstraint(oldrole)
cell.imageview1.addConstraint(newrole)
```

When I run that I got a error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException',
>   reason: 'Unable to install constraint on view.  Does the constraint
>   reference something from outside the subtree of the view?  That's
>   illegal.

Comment: That code makes no sense to me. You are creating two new instances of an NSLayoutConstraint, and removing one that's never been added (oldrole).

Comment: How can I remove a contraint I did add on IB? 
I thought it was so ...

Comment: Do I have to remove all the contraints and add the new ones?

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you need to create custom cell class, where you will have your constraint `IBOutlet` property from nib file. Then you can just remove it and add new leading space constraint.